# Python code to find a all paths from given dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, while-loop, combinations

I need to find a way so that i get all possible paths for given set of dictionary values. For example:

In this case we start from point 1 and we want to reach 7:

```
k = dict()

k[1] = [(1,2),(1,7)]
k[2] = [(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)]
k[3] = [(3,6),(3,7)]
```

```
One of the outputs would for example be: [(1,2),(2,3),(3,7)]
```

I'm really struggling to find a recursive method for this.

Comment: When you mean a path, you mean that your array represent a 2D grid? Then you can simply use a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `k` like so. There is probably a better way depending on your actual goal, but this shows how to get to every tuple (`t`) value:

```
for key in k.keys():
  for t in k[key]:
    print(f"key = {key}, tuple values = ({t[0]}, {t[1]})")
```

Answer (score 0):

Model the problem as [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) and perform [Depth First search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) since objective is to achieve via recursion.

```
graph = { 
    1 : [2, 7], 
    2 : [3, 4, 5], 
    3 : [6, 7], 
    4 : [2],
    5 : [2],
    6 : [3],
    7 : [1, 3]
    }   

vertex = 7 
visited = [False] * (vertex + 1)
path = []


def any_path(src, dest, visited, path):

    # Mark the current node as visited and store in path
    visited[src] = True
    path.append(src)

    # If current vertex is same as destination
    if src == dest:
        return True

    # If current vertex is not destination
    # Recursively call for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    for neighbor in graph[src]:
        if not visited[neighbor] and any_path(neighbor, dest, visited, path):
            return True

    # Remove current vertex from path[]
    path.pop()
    return False


any_path(1, 7, visited, path)


print (path)
```

The output of paths will be like this

> [1, 2, 3, 7]

We can use [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) to achieve the desired output of

> [(1,2), (2,3), (3, 7)]